# Does XACML distinguish between "attribute value is null" and "attribute is missing"

Tags: xacml, xacml3

I am reading [latest XACML specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html) and as far as I can see, there is no notion of `null` for attribute values. **Is this true?**

So, am I right saying that `AttributeDesignator` with `MustBePresent=false` should return empty bag if requested attribute's value is `null`? And vice versa, `AttributeDesignator` with `MustBePresent=true` should return `Indeterminate` if requested attribute's value is `null`?

**So, is it true that XACML is not able to distinguish between "attribute value is null" and "attribute is missing" situations?**

Or is that just out of the scope of the standard and is implementation-dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XACML an AttributeDesignator conceptually evaluates to a bag of attribute values. That bag may be empty.

As far as I know none of the XACML datatypes can have null values. i.e. there is no concept of null attribute value in XACML.

However, do note though that an empty string is a valid string, although it's not null.